# Windows Store App, VPN, RAS Api

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, vpn, ras

Our windows store app allows user to manage (create or dial) VPN profiles.

For this functionality we use
RAS Api (create and dial VPN profile)
[RAS Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446741%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Wlan Api (listen to wifi networks) - will be changed to classes with Windows.Networking.Connectivity in windows8
[Wlan Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

We face following troubles for Windows Store application:

1. RAS API functions don't work properly under windows store application template (as example RasEnumDevices return error code 5 - Access Denied).
   However it works good from desktop application launched on windows 8.
   Question: how we could get RAS API to work under window store applications? If that is absolutely impossible - is there any other way to create VPN connection in app developed for Windows Store?
2. All user's VPN profiles stored by Windows OS in "..\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk", file could be found on file system manually, but we don't have access to this file via API, either we can't access it directrly. Current workarround uses own created PBK file located in users profile folder.
   Question: how we could get access to system VPN connections stored in OS.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Hotspot Shield VPN for Windows offers private browsing to ensure the privacy of your web session.
Check it out here: http://www.anchorfree.com/hotspot-shield-VPN-download-windows.php